# Android: How to force close activity and start again from receier?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have Cordova/Angular based app with somu installed 3rd party plugins. App have some recivers which should on receive run main activity on given URL.

It works fine but on calling activty from receiver is app not everytime initialized.

I thought that is it some problem with Javascript initialization but is not.

Is it problem regarding how activity is started.

Main Activity has set launchmode: un Manifest to:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

And Other activities to the:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

And I'm able to start activity from receiver with these flags:

```
//intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                //intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                //intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                //intentOne.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

I tried a lot of combination of the flags and settings fow Manifest file, but no one from these worked for me correctly.

Could somebody try to help me with this issue?

I think that solution could be reset running main activity and start it completely again on different URL, but i don't know how exactly do it..

Thanks for any help.

Here is the code onCreate:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();

        // GET PASSED PARAMS (CALLED PHONE NUMBER, ETC)
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        dialedNumber = b.getString("phone_number");
        urlToCall = "file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/call-result/"+dialedNumber;

        if(dialedNumber != null && !dialedNumber.isEmpty() )
        {
            super.loadUrl(urlToCall);
        } else {
            super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is exactly the behavior of the main activity when you say " works fine but on calling activity from receiver is app not every time initialized".

Comment: It is quite strange behaviour, first time all plugins works fine, but on second time for examples charts, or sliders in template view are not displayed.

Comment: it is possible to be a problem of launchmode(top single)and new intent which is created by the system to launch the activies whith that launchmode

Comment: What changes do you suggest to do?

Answer (score 0):

try to override onNewIntent before your OnCreate:

@Override

protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

```
super.onNewIntent(intent);

setIntent(intent);
```

}

Comment: I tried it place before on create but result is still same, should i use condition here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using installing version v. 1.3, vhich solving this issue:
https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin